# Shutdown freeze issue on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 22.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Lenovo Legion 5 laptop. It is a dual boot along side Windows 11. I am able to shutdown the laptop from Windows without any issue. However, when I attempt to shutdown or restart from my Ubuntu, the shutdown freezes and never completes. I would need to perform a manual force shutdown every time.

I tried a widely recommended fix for this by updating the grub file in `/etc/default/grub`. I made the following change as well :

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force "`

`sudo update-grub`

Any further recommendation on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same specs and I am facing the same issue. Power-off journal entries (`journalctl -rb -1`) seem normal and suggest that the shutdown process was completed within a minute but the logos of Ubuntu and LEGION remain on indefinitely, until I push the power button.

Apparently, this seems to be a [nouveau driver related bug](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/15mp0nl/ubuntu_22043_lts_doesnt_shut_down/jzfdagb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) which has been patched but needs to be released for Ubuntu. Eagerly awaiting an update on this.